# When I plug my TL-W722N nothing happens

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

When I type `ip a` neither my wlan0, nor my Realtek appears.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:16:45:56:8e:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:6b:f8:1f:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp6s0
       valid_lft 85594sec preferred_lft 85594sec
    inet6 fe80::d36:d0eb:813b:8941/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Also when I plug it in, this happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAWoj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type `sudo journalctl -fn`. After that plug in the device and check the messages. It's not the solution yet, but a first step to find out the problem. Probably some firmware is missing.

Comment: I think I got what happened. When I open Virtual box it happens, but I don't know why or how to fix it.

Comment: Probably virtualbox starts one or more virtual interfaces for bridging or host-only networks. type `ip l` before starting virtualbox and again after you've started it. Check the differences, if a new interface has been added.